# Busy indicator not working when started and stopped within same method

Tags: angularjs, busyindicator

I am trying to implement a Busy indicator in my AngularJS application. I have got few samples, one of which is using angular-Spinner. In my application, when I perform an operation via button click, I call some other factory method to do an operation which takes sometime (in secs). So at start of the method, I start the spinner and at end of the method I stop the spinner. This doesnt work. But in case of asynchronous call spinner works fine. I am not sure whether I am missing something. Please find below the code snippet. Thanks in advance.

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['angularSpinner']);
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'usSpinnerService','$rootScope', function($scope, usSpinnerService, $rootScope) {
$scope.startcounter = 0;
$scope.startSpin = function() {
  if (!$scope.spinneractive) {
    usSpinnerService.spin('spinner-1');
    $scope.startcounter++;
  }
};

$scope.stopSpin = function() {
  if ($scope.spinneractive) {
    usSpinnerService.stop('spinner-1');
  }
};

$scope.DoSomeAction = function(){
  usSpinnerService.spin('spinner-1');

  for(var i=0; i<999999; i++){
    console.log(i);
  }
  usSpinnerService.stop('spinner-1');

};
$scope.spinneractive = false;

$rootScope.$on('us-spinner:spin', function(event, key) {
  $scope.spinneractive = true;
});

$rootScope.$on('us-spinner:stop', function(event, key) {
  $scope.spinneractive = false;
}); }]);
```

Spinner code:

```
/**
* angular-spinner version 0.5.0
* License: MIT.
* Copyright (C) 2013, 2014, Uri Shaked and contributors.
*/

(function (root) {
'use strict';

function factory(angular, Spinner) {

    angular
        .module('angularSpinner', [])

        .factory('usSpinnerService', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
            var config = {};

            config.spin = function (key) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('us-spinner:spin', key);
            };

            config.stop = function (key) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('us-spinner:stop', key);
            };

            return config;
        }])

        .directive('usSpinner', ['$window', function ($window) {
            return {
                scope: true,
                link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                    var SpinnerConstructor = Spinner || $window.Spinner;

                    scope.spinner = null;

                    scope.key = angular.isDefined(attr.spinnerKey) ? attr.spinnerKey : false;

                    scope.startActive = angular.isDefined(attr.spinnerStartActive) ?
                        attr.spinnerStartActive : scope.key ?
                        false : true;

                    scope.spin = function () {
                        if (scope.spinner) {
                            scope.spinner.spin(element[0]);
                        }
                    };

                    scope.stop = function () {
                        if (scope.spinner) {
                            scope.spinner.stop();
                        }
                    };

                    scope.$watch(attr.usSpinner, function (options) {
                        scope.stop();
                        scope.spinner = new SpinnerConstructor(options);
                        if (!scope.key || scope.startActive) {
                            scope.spinner.spin(element[0]);
                        }
                    }, true);

                    scope.$on('us-spinner:spin', function (event, key) {
                        if (key === scope.key) {
                            scope.spin();
                        }
                    });

                    scope.$on('us-spinner:stop', function (event, key) {
                        if (key === scope.key) {
                            scope.stop();
                        }
                    });

                    scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                        scope.stop();
                        scope.spinner = null;
                    });
                }
            };
        }]);
}

if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    /* AMD module */
    define(['angular', 'spin'], factory);
} else {
    /* Browser global */
    factory(root.angular);
}
}(window));
```

Comment: Show us the `usSpinnerService` code

Comment: I have added usSpinnerService code.

Comment: What do you mean by it works with async calls?

Comment: Sam,  I meant like $http calls instead of a for loop blocking the execution